# Tree that contains points - improvement needed

Tags: algorithm, tree

Currently, I'm making my own structure that holds points in 2D space. I know that there are many ready-made algorithms and kind of trees but I want to have something lightweight. So I have (x, y) point that is inside of each node, each node contains 4 children: topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight next node.

### Inserting:

Every new node is inserted depends on its position.
If the tree **is empty**, insert the new node / If the tree **is not empty**, go to the first node and do:
1. Decide what is the position of the current node in regard of the new node.
2. If it is e. g. topLeft and it is not occupied then insert the new node.
3. If position topLeft is occupied go to this node and repeat.

### Removing:

The structure I need does not need to have "removing particular node" function, so if the job is done the destructor deletes the whole tree recursively.

### Check if the node is inside of particular area:

If the tree is not empty go the first node and then:
1. Check if given area's x is less than node's x and area's y is less than node's y if it is then go to the topLeft children node (if it exists).
2. The same for the topRight (check area's x + width position and y).
3. The same for botRight (check area's x + width and y + height).
4. The same for botLeft (check area's x and y + height).
5. Check if current node is inside of area if it is do stuff you want to do with a point. Recursively go back and repeat.

That's how my structure looks like, the image shows which bonds would be checked for particular area (**orange** color):
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArzFI.png)

My question is, is there is a better algorithm? What Can I improve? I saw quadtree but it seems to be different and it contains more data. I need something that can easily hold moving objects in 2D. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So you're trying to store the object's relationship to other objects? How does that help you keep track of moving objects in two dimensions? Won't an object's relationship to other objects change as it moves?

Comment: I've made a mistake, I was testing my tree without changing the x, y, you've made me realize that it does not work for 'loose' objects, do you know any structure that can hold moving objects? I know that boost has some own implementations but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is basically a quadtree, but you use your data for doing splits instead of the typical middle.

You can improve the system a bit by switching to a [KD tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). It's similar except at each point you split along a single dimension. The main difference is that you only have two pointers per node (instead of 4) so you save about half the memory.

Another thing is that you split your space until you get to 1 point. Because modern CPUs do really fancy things, for small values, linear search will be faster than traversing the tree. So I would only split a space when you have 50-100 points already in there. This will also save a bunch of pointers that don't need to stored at all.

If you know something about the distribution of your points you might be able to do something better. If the distribution is kinda uniform you can simply chunk your space into uniform cells and store the points in the associated cells. A rule of thumb says if you have N points you should have sqrt(N) cells, but you should try and see what works best.